# Prevent git from pushing some files

Tags: git, github

I have a git project with an Xcode project. I need to use git branches to add features to the projects, and I also need that by checking out branches git updates the Xcode project data, along with the source files.

This Xcode project is only mine and it wouldn't work on other computers.

What I'm trying to achieve is making git update the project on branch checkout, but this project should not be pushed to the server.

Comment: Sounds like you should consider forking the project. Then you don't have to worry about pushing unwanted code to the original repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Git Hooks are scripts that are executed every time a certain stage in your workflow is reached, e.g. pre-commit, post-commit, **post-checkout**, etc. They are part of your local Git repository and will not be committed or pushed.

For your use case, you will likely want to create a `post-checkout` hook:

> After you run a successful git checkout, the post-checkout hook runs; you can use it to set up your working directory properly for your project environment.

To do so, create a file called `post-checkout` in the directory `<your_repository>/.git/hooks/` and make sure that it is executable. In that file, you can now write a script for the logic that should be executed after every checkout, i.e. moving your Xcode files around.

Be sure to read the Git Book chapter I've linked above to get a better understanding of Git Hooks, as well as an overview over the different kinds of Hooks.